# jQuery UI: change resizable handles after init

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Consider an element is initialized with jQuery UI resizable widget

```
$(selector).resizable({handles:'se'});
```

And later the handles are changed

```
$(selector).resizable('option','handles','sw');
```

The result of `console.log( $(selector).resizable('option',handles') );` shows `sw`
But it seems the resizable widget does not reflect with this change.

Is there a way to somehow refresh the resizable widget after such modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a [bug in jQueryUI](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3423).

There is a workaround however (slightly hacky though):

Add the following class to your CSS:

```
.ui-hide-handler {
    width:0 !important;
    height:0 !important;
}
```

And remove the classes accordingly:

```
$('.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se', selector).addClass('ui-hide-handler');
$('.ui-resizable-sw', selector).addClass('ui-hide-handler');
```

So in your case:

```
$('.ui-resizable-handle', selector).addClass("ui-hide-handler");
$('.ui-resizable-sw', selector).removeClass('ui-hide-handler');
```

Comment: Looks like they have fixed the bug, but it hasn't quite been released yet (looks like it will be in 1.12)